# How to add multiple strings in NSMutableString separated by comma

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a comma separated string inside loop like this :-

```
string=@"A,B,C,D,E";
```

I did something like this :

```
for (int j=0; j<_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal.count; j++)    
{    
  NSMutableDictionary *paypalArrayDataInDictionary=[_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal objectAtIndex:j];    
  [productNameDetail appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", [paypalArrayDataInDictionary objectForKey:@"PRODUCT"]]];    
}
```

Here `_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal` is my `MutableArray` getting from `plist`.

Comment: what the output u need

Comment: I need something like that.
string="A,B,C,D,E";

Comment: can you print `_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get array of `PRODUCT` from the `_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal` and then use [`componentsJoinedByString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsarray/1412075-componentsjoinedbystring?language=objc) on it to get the string separated by `,`.

```
NSArray *products = [_arrayToCarryDataFromCartToPaymentPageInPaypal valueForKey:@"PRODUCT"];
NSString *str = [products componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Welcome mate :)